# Loop Through Variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a bash script to use rsync and update files on about 20 different servers.

I have the rsync part figured out. What I'm having trouble with is going through a list of variables.

My script thus far look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER1="192.xxx.xxx.2"
SERVER2="192.xxx.xxx.3"
SERVER3="192.xxx.xxx.4"
SERVER4="192.xxx.xxx.5"
SERVER5="192.xxx.xxx.6"
SERVER6="192.xxx.xxx.7"

for ((i=1; i<7; i++))
do
    echo [Server IP Address]
done
```

Where `[Server IP Address]` should be the value of the associated variable. So when i = 1 I should echo the value of $SERVER1.

I've tried several iterations of this including

```
echo "$SERVER$i"    # printed the value of i
echo "SERVER$i"     # printer "SERVER" plus the value of i ex: SERVER 1 where i = 1
echo $("SERVER$i")  # produced an error SERVER1: command not found where i = 1
echo $$SERVER$i     # printed a four digit number followed by "SERVER" plus the value of i
echo \$$SERVER$i    # printed "$" plus the value of i
```

It has been a long time since I scripted so I know I am missing something. Plus I'm sure I'm mixing in what I could do using C#, which I've used for the past 11 years.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Or should I be putting these values in an array and looping through the array? I need to this same thing for production IP addresses as well as location names.

This is all in an effort to not have to repeat a block of code I will be using to sync the files on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses and comments. I will more than likely take the array approach.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use an array.

```
#! /bin/bash
servers=( 192.xxx.xxx.2 192.xxx.xxx.3
          192.xxx.xxx.4 192.xxx.xxx.5
          192.xxx.xxx.6 192.xxx.xxx.7
)

for server in "${servers[@]}" ; do
    echo "$server"
done
```

Comment: +1; and note that you can put arbitrary whitespace before/after/between the array elements, so you can (if desired) put one element per line as in the OP.

Comment: @ruakh: thanks, updated to show what can be done.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twice! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 32):

As the other answers point out, an array is the most convenient way to do this.  However, for completeness, the exact thing you are asking for is [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).  Rewritten as follows, your sample will also work using this method:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER1="192.xxx.xxx.2"
SERVER2="192.xxx.xxx.3"
SERVER3="192.xxx.xxx.4"
SERVER4="192.xxx.xxx.5"
SERVER5="192.xxx.xxx.6"
SERVER6="192.xxx.xxx.7"

for ((i=1; i<7; i++))
do
    servervar="SERVER$i"
    echo "${!servervar}"
done
```

---

If you're OK with just putting the list of IP addresses in the the `for` loop, then you might also consider simply using some brace expansions to iterate over whatever you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

for server in \
192.xxx.xxx.{2..7} \
192.yyy.yyy.{42..50} \
192.zzz.zzz.254
do
    echo "$server"
done
```

But if you need to reuse the (possibly brace-expanded) list, then using the list to initialize an array would be the way to go:

```
#!/bin/bash

servers=(
192.xxx.xxx.{2..7} 
192.yyy.yyy.{42..50}
192.zzz.zzz.254 )

for server in "${servers[@]}"
do
    echo "$server"
done
```

Comment: +1. While arrays are relevant to many types of problems, they don't actually answer the question. I came here looking for an answer which arrays weren't suitable for, and you provided.

Answer (score 15):

While I would probably go with one of the array answers myself, I’d like to point out that it is possible to loop over names directly. You can do

```
for name in "${!SERVER*}"; do
    echo "${!name}"
done
```

or, in 4.3 and up, you can use a `nameref`:

```
declare -n name
for name in "${!SERVER*}"; do
    echo "$name"
done
```

Hat tip [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) for the < 4.3 solution.

Comment: Indirect expansion (`${!var}`) works with older versions of Bash too: `foo1=aa; foo2=bbb; foox=cccc; for p in "${!foo@}"; do echo "$p = ${!p}"; done`

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for the assist. I've updated my answer.

Comment: For me, this rather prints the variables name rather than the value?

Answer (score 6):

Everyone who said you should use an array is correct, but -- as an academic exercise -- if you were determined to do it with separate variables ending in a number (SERVER1, SERVER2, etc.), this is how you'd do it:

```
for ((i=1; i<7; i++))
do
    eval echo \"\$SERVER$i\"
done
```

Comment: `eval` is hard to use safely.  Yes this can work, but bash indirect expansion is a better way in general.

Comment: Habit. When I started writing shell scripts, even in bash, there was no indirect expansion. "eval" is perfectly safe if you understand how to escape properly. Still, I agree with you that indirect expansion is better...but the old ways still work.  I wouldn't do either in this case anyway.  I'd use an array!

Comment: In this case, notice that you didn't escape the double quotes, so after `eval` is done, you have `echo $SERVER1`, not `echo "$SERVER1"`.  Yes possible to use safely, but *very easy* to use unsafely or not how you intended!

Comment: Since a server name would contain no spaces, it wouldn't have mattered in this case anyway...but you are right, the double-quotes should be escaped.  Fixed in answer!

Comment: Right, removing the double-quotes entirely (to avoid the misleading impression that they were protecting anything) would be the other option.  But escaping them too is the more generic way, so +1.